# iOS: merge two videos, one of the videos not displays but sound is playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

i'm trying to merge 2 videos, one that I downloaded from youtube and one that i took with UIImagePickerController.
after the merge the youtube's video not display but sound is playing.
i guess that the problem caused by the diffrences between the videos dimensions.

this is my code, what am i doing wrong ?

```
- (void) MergeVideos {
NSLog(@"start merge");
NSError *avError = nil;
//NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

for (int i = ((int)[videos_arr2 count]-1); i>= 0; i--) {
    AVURLAsset *tmpAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videos_arr2[i] options:nil];

[composition insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, tmpAsset.duration) ofAsset:tmpAsset atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&avError];
}

AVAssetExportSession *export = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

export.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *outputURL = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movie"] ;
[manager createDirectoryAtPath:outputURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

outputURL = [outputURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movie.mp4"];
[manager removeItemAtPath:outputURL error:nil];

export.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputURL];

[export exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) {
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:export.outputURL];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)                                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];
    player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [player prepareToPlay];
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [player setShouldAutoplay:NO];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:player];
}];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are inserting both AVAssets at kCMTimeZero. You should insert the next asset at the previous Asset's duration:

```
CMTime nextAddTime = kCMTimeZero;
for (int i = ((int)[videos_arr2 count]-1); i>= 0; i--) {
    AVURLAsset *tmpAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videos_arr2[i] options:nil];

[composition insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, tmpAsset.duration) ofAsset:tmpAsset atTime:nextAddTime error:&avError];
nextAddTime = CMTimeAdd(nextAddTime, tmpAsset.duration);
}
```

Comment: Are you ever pushing the MPMovieController onto the stack? You should also make sure that both Assets are local Assets.You might also try to use the [UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW41) function to save the video to the photos album to see if it plays back there.